# if metrics are equivalent then $m d_1(x,y) < d_2(x,y) < M d_1(x,y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have studied following definition of equivalent metric spaces:

Two metrics on a set $X$ are said to be equivalent if and only if they induce the same topology on $X$.
Now I tried to prove that:

$$ d_1 ,d_2 $$
are equivalent iff there exist positive constants $m$ and $M$ such that
$$ md_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le Md_1(x,y)$$
for all
$$ x,y\in X $$
I proved that if
$$ md_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le Md_1(x,y)$$
then these metrics are equivalent.
but I couldn't prove if theses metrics are equivalent then
$$ md_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le Md_1(x,y)$$

I tried to take an element $x$ then
$$ {B_d}_1(x,\epsilon)  $$
is a open set in $d_1$ then it is a open set in $d_2$ then for any
$$ y\in {B_d}_1(x,\epsilon), \exists r>0 : {B_d}_2(y,r) \subset {B_d}_1(x,\epsilon) $$
but I can't complete and I think this way is not successful because $r$ is not constant. it change when $y$ change.

Comment: Counter-example: $|x-y|$ and $\frac  {|x-y|} {1+|x-y|}$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your condition for the metrics is called Lipschitz equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

> but I couldn't prove if theses metrics are equivalent then
> $$md_1(x,y)≤d_2(x,y)≤Md_1(x,y)$$

This  is because it is not true.  The given inequalities describe "bi-Lipschitz equivalence", which is stronger than topological equivalence.   For example, the metrics $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|x-y|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on $\mathbb R$ are topologically equivalent, but not bi-Lipschitz equivalent, since you cannot find such constants ($\frac{d_1(0,x)}{d_2(0,x)}\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$, while $\frac{d_1(0,x)}{d_2(0,x)}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.)

Comment: then the question is wrong :( ok. thank you very much

Comment: @A12345 Just curious, was this a problem in a textbook? And if so, which one?

Comment: No it is papers from a student. I heard that  he has writed some imporatant questions from a book in these papers but I saw many errors in them. actullay he has proved this false question but his proof is false. so I tried to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

If A is,open in $d_{1} $ then for any $x \in A $ exists $r$ such

If $ d_{1}(x,y) <r $ then $y \in A $ If we want A to be open in  $ d_{2}(x,y) $ we have to find another radius. Let us $R = \frac{r}{M} $ from inequality mentioned in definition we have containing one ball in another. second part of equivalence we prove in similar way

Comment: I have proved that already.I didn't write that because it's long.Now I ask about if theses metrics are equivalent then this inequality verifies